# How to write a Loop

Tags: c#

I am working on something and I am stumped with 2 things.

The first is, I am trying to make a sort of counter that uses `PostMessage` to type from 0000 to 3600.
I need it to stop every few times it PostMessage the number and execute another part of the code, then after that code is done continue for another say 10 times then execute that same code, and so on.

Second: I need a function that will detect if a certain color is in a certain pixel, and if it is then it will execute some more code.

Here's the code that I tried, but failed with:

```
void loop()
{
    int start = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
    for (int i = start;i == 9999; i++)
        if(i == 0004)
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, i, 0);
}
```

Here's the last version, which also does not work:

```
void function()       
{       
    for (int i = 0000; i <= 3600; i++)       
    {       
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, i, 0); //PostMessage i       
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x0d, 0x1c0001); //Press Return       
        Sleep(1000); //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep       
        if ((i % 4) == 0)       
        {       
            Execute(); //My Code Block to execute after i tries 4 times.       
        }       
    }       
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the code you have written so far? People don't generally like to just write your code for you...

Comment: don't really have a code, i just need a function that will write 0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, then execute another function, then continue, 0004, 0005, 0006, 0007 then execute the same function, and so forth.

Comment: Your question is very vague and not really to the point, also as it is really two questions you should have opened two separate questions. Please be sure to show that you have attempted to research something before blindly asking for an answer.

Comment: Still trying to crack that PIN, Brandon?

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudocode to get you started on your first issue:

```
for number = 0 to 3600
    print number
    if number mod 10 = 0
        do other stuff
end
```

or in C#:

```
for(int number = 0; number <= 3600; number++) { // decide < vs <=
    Print(number); // TODO: this function
    if((number % 10) == 0) {
        DoOtherStuff(); // TODO: this function
    }
}
```

Post what you've actually managed to do so far and I'm sure people will be able to be more specific.  The problem is an extremely basic loop function so you must be able to at least get something.

Comment: I don't like it. Why a modulus, if you can more directly express the desired semantics by just nesting another for-loop?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to suggest a nested loop... modulus makes perfect sense here.

Comment: (I hope you don't mind me editing a C# version to match the tags; if this is a problem just hit the "rollback" button on the edit-history)

Comment: No problem Marc, originally I didn't give C# code as I thought maybe that was the point of his exercise, but from his answers it looks like he's more at the level of understanding the basic concepts of modulus and loops, so no problem using the C# if it'll help him understand what's going on.